# Connection being refused while sending data from Android app to server

Tags: java, android, phpmyadmin

I'm new to android application development and i want to send three parameters Latitude ,
Longitude and Bimari(which i am mentioning in 
my code below) to phpMyAdmin server via internet.
The problem is that after selecting bimari from 
spinner when i click send button my app crashes.
My server side is working correctly.Can anyone
please tell me why i can't send my data to server ?

Thanks alot for reading !

MainActivity.java is as follows:-

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.sushma.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";


String nn, nn1, nn2, nn3, nn4, nn5, nnf;  // used to make URL
String sss1, sss2;  // used to convert lat and long to string
String s; // used to save bimari as string

double lat, lng;
LocationManager lm;

String provider;
Location l;
private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lm = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, false);
    l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (l != null) {

     //get latitude and longitude of the location
     lng = l.getLongitude();
     lat = l.getLatitude();

     } else {
    System.out.println("No lat/long");

    }

    {


        LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        l1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ambulance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}


public void ongobuttonclick(View view) {
    this.view = view;

    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.problems);

    s = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    sss1 = String.valueOf(lng);
    sss2 = String.valueOf(lat);

    nn = "http://192.168.2.8/tech/new_predict.php?Latitude=";
    nn1 = sss2;
    nn2 = "&Longitude=";
    nn3 = sss1;
    nn4 = "&Bimari=";
    nn5 = s;

    nnf = nn + nn1 + nn2 + nn3 + nn4 + nn5;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httPost = new HttpPost(nnf);
    System.out.println(nnf);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                httpclient.execute(httPost);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Logcat

```
01-26 19:32:22.859  14247-14247/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-26 19:32:29.085  14247-14247/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-26 19:32:29.085  14247-14247/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40da9930)
01-26 19:32:29.105  14247-14247/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3804)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
        at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3799)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
        at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        at com.example.sushma.myfirstapp.MainActivity.ongobuttonclick(MainActivity.java:176)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3799)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
        at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NewLogcat

```
01-26 22:45:48.807  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
01-26 22:45:48.807  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11750: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
01-26 22:45:48.867  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-26 22:45:48.867  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
01-26 22:45:48.867  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11756: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
01-26 22:45:48.867  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-26 22:45:48.867  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
01-26 22:45:48.867  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9401: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
01-26 22:45:48.867  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
01-26 22:45:48.887  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-26 22:45:48.887  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 534: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-26 22:45:48.887  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-26 22:45:48.887  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-26 22:45:48.887  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 556: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-26 22:45:48.887  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-26 22:45:48.947  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 157K, 13% free 8676K/9872K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
01-26 22:45:48.957  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 10.654MB for 1228816-byte allocation
01-26 22:45:48.967  23318-23329/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 9875K/11076K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-26 22:45:49.007  23318-23323/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp E/dalvikvm﹕ adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
01-26 22:45:49.007  23318-23323/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 11% free 9871K/11076K, paused 16ms+3ms, total 40ms
01-26 22:45:49.257  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hawaii.so
01-26 22:45:49.267  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/﹕ mem_init ++
01-26 22:45:49.267  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/﹕ gHwMemAllocator client 3
01-26 22:45:49.267  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/﹕ **** Using ION allocator ****
01-26 22:45:49.267  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/﹕ registered SIGUSR1[10] for pid[23318]
01-26 22:45:49.267  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/﹕ HwMemAllocatorImpl Static Counters 0 0
01-26 22:45:49.267  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/﹕ HwMemAllocatorImpl[490a9dcc] totalDeviceAllocSize[0] totalFree[0] maxFree[0] in numSlabs[0]
01-26 22:45:49.277  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/﹕ mem_init 490a9dcc--
01-26 22:45:49.277  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/ION﹕ config: version(0x10000) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x22d) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x608)
01-26 22:45:49.277  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/MM_DEVICE﹕ Waiting for mm thread to come up
01-26 22:45:49.277  23318-23346/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/MM_DEVICE﹕ mm_device_thread starting
01-26 22:45:49.277  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglCreateContext() config: 18 context: 0x4f3c4db8, VC context 1, Thread 23318
01-26 22:45:49.277  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
01-26 22:45:49.287  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4beeea48, VC surface: 1, Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:49.287  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4f3c4db8, 0x4beeea48, 0x4beeea48) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:49.287  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-26 22:45:50.849  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-26 22:45:50.959  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
01-26 22:45:50.969  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4c0f1be8, VC surface: 2, Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:50.969  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4f3c4db8, 0x4c0f1be8, 0x4c0f1be8) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:50.989  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-26 22:45:50.999  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4f3c4db8, 0x4beeea48, 0x4beeea48) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:50.999  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-26 22:45:50.999  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-26 22:45:50.999  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4f3c4db8, 0x4c0f1be8, 0x4c0f1be8) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:51.079  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-26 22:45:51.089  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4f3c4db8, 0x4beeea48, 0x4beeea48) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:52.150  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4f3c4db8, 0x4c0f1be8, 0x4c0f1be8) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:52.791  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
01-26 22:45:52.791  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:52.791  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4c0f1be8, android window 0x4c05c8f8, Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:52.811  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4f3c4db8, 0x4beeea48, 0x4beeea48) Thread: 23318
01-26 22:45:52.871  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-26 22:45:53.802  23318-23318/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp I/System.out﹕ http://192.168.2.8/tech/new_predict.php?Latitude=31.310573780338718&Longitude=75.55498407042245&Bimari=Bones
01-26 22:45:56.945  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.2.8 refused
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at  org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.sushma.myfirstapp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:173)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-26 22:45:56.955  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.2.8 (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at     org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ ... 8 more
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-26 22:45:56.965  23318-23498/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ ... 13 more
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried execute `httpclient.execute(httPost);` method in UI thread. You can not do this.

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to resolve this issue.

```
public void ongobuttonclick(View view) {

     ...
    //your code 

    //use AsyncTask if you  want ot inform ui thread
     final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost httPost = new HttpPost(nnf);

    new AsyncTask<HttpPost, Void, HttpResponse>() {
        //YourParams, YourProgress, YourResult can be Void
        @Override
        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(HttpPost... params) {
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
               response = httpclient.execute(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response) {
            if(response != null){
                //do sth in UI thread
            }
        }
    }.execute(httPost);

    //or in new thread if you doesn't want ot inform ui thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                httpclient.execute(httPost);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: okay sir , but i would be very thankful if you could guide me where i have to execute httpclient.execute(httPost); . I am really a novice in android.

Comment: wait I will edit my post

Comment: Sir actually i have tried to use Async Task already but couldn't understand (protected string doInBackground(String... urls)) string as return type , as i have to post my variables on server , i don't need to return anything . So how can i proceed further . If anyways you could sum up that part of code and post it here i would be extremely thankful

Comment: One more question isn't Async Task for downloading stuff from a web page ?

Comment: I give you two solution first is how to use AsyncTask the second is how to use thread

Comment: I show you how to execute your httPost if you want to do something with this you have to handle response

Comment: Look on my post one more time. I edited AsyncTask. Do you see? How you execute your request in some thread and you can handle it in UI thread

Comment: Okay sir so let me sum up just to clarify myself                                      There are two solutions                                                                         In the first one that is async task                                                           Do i need to pass any parameters                                                     or just the way you have posted it on ?                                                      Ques 2    If i use the second method of new thread do i need to pass anything as parameter

Comment: I made one more edit. You have two solution First with AsyncTask the second with thread. If you want to do something with HttpResponse on UI thread you have to use AsyncTask and do it in postExecute method as is shown in code in post. If you want just execute http request and you doesn't care about HttpResponse you can use Thread

Comment: Sir according to my requirement i implemented the second way                  and i am just left with the following two errors                                                01-26 22:23:53.714  21425-21425/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-26 22:23:58.959  21425-22036/com.example.sushma.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.2.8 refused

Comment: Did you try open this url in phone by browser? You get Connection to 192.168.2.8 refused. You can be in different network than server

Comment: Sir i have edited my code above in MainActivity.java                                   please have a look(using a new thread)                                                        And regarding connection my browser is on my laptop where i am running phpmyadmin server                                                               and i am testing my app on my mobile  .                                      And my phone and laptop(server) are connected to the same wifi network .

Comment: Could you attach your log?

Comment: Sir i have attached my new logcat

Comment: It's look that problem is on server site. Try open http://192.168.2.8/tech/new_predict.php?Latitude=31.310573780338718&Longitude=75.55498407042245&Bimari=Bones this link in some browser on your phone.